# cx_Freeze - module is included on freeze, but not used properly

Tags: python, pyqt, cx-freeze

I have written an application using PyQt5 along with pyqtgraph that uses qt_backport to give pyqtgraph support for PyQt5, since pyqtgraph does not currently support PyQt5. I am trying to use cx_Freeze to create an executable for this application, but am running into the following error:

[image]

This occurs when I try and open the application. cx_Freeze doesn't throw any errors when the building is actually occurring. qt_backport is included within the library zip folder that is generated by cx_Freeze when it builds the application. Here is a pastebin of the output from running

```
python setup.py build
```

http://pastebin.com/yDSvHULH

The application runs fine when I just run it as a python script, so I'm not sure what is going on here. My setup.py file looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'includes': ['atexit', 'qt_backport'],
        'packages': 'qt_backport'
    }
}

executables = [
    Executable('DataViewer.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='DataViewer',
      version='0.1',
      description='Application for viewing Prairie-generated csv data files',
      options=options,
      executables=executables
      )
```

I should note that I have tested a simple PyQt5 application with cx_Freeze and everything works fine, so the issue is specific to what's going on here (rather than a larger issue with my python / cx_Freeze installation)

Edit:
Using py2exe produces the same type of error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DataViewer.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\pyqt5\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .Qt import QtGui
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\pyqt5\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\Qt.py", line 71, in <module>
    raise Exception(msg)
Exception: PyQtGraph requires one of ('PySide', 'PyQt4'), but none of these could be imported. PyQt5 was detected, but to use it you you must also install qt_backport.
```

Once again, the qt_backport folder, along with the files that are supposed to be in that folder, are within the library zip file.